# Vue get $index in two levels of v-for

Tags: vue.js

Here is a table with Vue.

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="height in chartHeight" track-by="$index">
        <td class="item" v-for="width in chartWidth" track-by="$index">
            index of row and column here
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The height `$index` is overriden by that of width inside. How can I access both `$index`?

Comment: Can you show a example for chartHeight and chartWidth?

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="(hid, height) in chartHeight" track-by="hid">
        <td class="item" v-for="(wid, width) in chartWidth" track-by="wid">
            {{ hid }}, {{ wid }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```